# Filtered port 22 with no firewall settings

Tags: firewall, port, centos5

I'm trying to connect to an sftp server from a CentOS 5.5 server. The connection is never established. When I run the command:
nmap -p 22 -P0 <sftp server address>

> PORT   STATE    SERVICE
>
> 22/tcp filtered ssh

I have similar development and staging servers on the same local network that are able to connect without any issues. There are no entries in iptables. Our firewall is setup to allow all outgoing requests. When I test the outgoing port 22 with: nmap -p 22 -P0 portquiz.net

> 22/tcp open  ssh

it appears to be open. So the problem only seems to happen when it's this one live server, connecting to a specific sftp server.
It's possible that the request is being blocked by a firewall on the end of the sftp server, but I don't understand why only this one server might be blocked. I was also able to connect to the sftp using a linode server that is outside our network.

This server was setup by somebody else. Are there any other settings on my end that could be causing this?

Comment: Can you provide a network map?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not exactly sure how it's all setup. We have a network admin that manages everything. I know there is a separate firewall that separates the WAN and LAN. He didn't spot anything in the logs that would indicate a request being blocked.

Comment: Are all your servers on the local network? or are some over the internet?

Comment: The sftp server is over the internet. The live, staging and dev servers that I'm trying to connect with are all in the local network (only live is not working). The linode server is also over the internet.

Comment: who is your ISP? and who is your hosting provider for your sftp server?

Comment: I believe our ISP is At&t. The sftp server is maintained by a separate company that we work with. It's possible there is a firewall on that end, but I don't understand why it might block this one server when we never used it to connect to that sftp in the past. I'm just trying to eliminate any problems that may be on my end.

Comment: Have your network admin verify AT&T isn't filtering port 22, and have the 3rd party company verify their not filtering it and that they have NAT rules set up properly.